# "tail -f | grep error" with while loop is not working

Tags: grep, scripting, pipe, tail

The below command is not giving any result. I want to `grep` the error line from the file and insert into table.

Command which is not working:

```
tail -f logfile.log | grep  ERROR|while read msg; do psql -d testdb -c insert into t values('$msg'); done
```

But if I remove the `grep ERROR` code from the command, it is working as expected. I am not sure what's going on?

Command which is working fine:

```
tail -f logfile.log|while read msg; do psql -d testdb -c insert into t values('$msg'); done
```

You can assume the below data in file:

```
ERROR
sql committed
ERROR
ERROR
error
...
```

Answer (score 6):

Two things:

1. The code, as it is written in the question, would insert the literal string `$msg` (if it works at all) since you use single quotes around it. Use double quotes instead. Here, I've put the whole statement in double quotes which will expand the `$msg` within. The shell code is still frail depending on what comes from the `grep`. The string in `$msg` should ideally be properly sanitized so that a single `'`, or other special characters, won't break the statement (or worse, see [comment from user *cas* below](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419538/tail-f-grep-error-with-while-loop-is-not-working#comment753990_419540)).

   ```
   tail -f logfile.log |
   grep -F 'ERROR' |
   while read msg; do
       psql -d testdb -c "insert into t values('$msg')"
   done
   ```

   I've also added `-F` to the `grep` invocation as we're searching with a fixed string (this is mostly for documentation purposes).
2. `grep` buffers its output, so it won't produce anything until its output buffer is full.  This gives the impression of it "not working" when in fact it does, but it won't do anything until `grep` has flushed its output buffer which it does once enough data is in it. This is a performance optimization.

   GNU `grep` (as well as some other implementations of the same utility, on e.g. OpenBSD) can be made to be line buffered with its `--line-buffered` option:

   ```
   tail -f logfile.log |
   grep --line-buffered -F 'ERROR' |
   while read msg; do
       psql -d testdb -c "insert into t values('$msg')"
   done
   ```

Note: I have not tested this since I currently do not have a PostgreSQL (?) instance running.

Comment: `--line-buffered` was [added to GNU `grep` for that very use case](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/commit/?id=1236f00774c60964d9c1661e7a8f6833d45596f5), before BSDs rewrote/forked their `grep` from GNU `grep` (which they used to use)

Comment: 3rd thing: It is possible for the contents of the ERROR message to break the SQL `insert` command (e.g. if it has a single-quote in it), or even pose an SQL injection threat (e.g. `ERROR something something '); drop table t; --`).  I **very strongly** recommend using perl or python or **any** other language that has a DB interface library that supports placeholders for variables in SQL statements.

Comment: A `perl` script using the `File::Tail` and `DBI` + `DBD::Pg` modules would be perfect for a job like this.